# Access denied nsis electron builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

When I package using `electron-builder`, it shows an error `access denied`, I came across a post that says it has something to do with the firewall but how will I disable it in windows.

**The Error**

```
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\566152007 C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1: Access is denied.
  ⨯ ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1\elevate.exe' -> 'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\dist\win-unpacked\resources\elevate.exe'  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1\elevate.exe' -> 'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\dist\win-unpacked\resources\elevate.exe' 
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
From previous event:
    at NsisTarget.buildInstaller (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:223:29)
    at NsisTarget.finishBuild (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:129:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at AsyncTaskManager.awaitTasks (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\builder-util\src\asyncTaskManager.ts:65:25)
    at Packager.doBuild (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:453:5)
    at Object.executeFinally (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)
    at Packager._build (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:376:31)
    at Packager.build (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:337:12)
    at Object.executeFinally (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\opcoin\download\app\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

**Package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "opcoin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "OpCoin Grabber",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^14.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.7"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.aryaanish.opcoin",
    "productName": "Op Coin Grabber",
    "target": "NSIS",
    "nsis": {
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "oneClick": false
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  }
}
```

**Fix**
I restarted my computer and it worked but the correct answer is given by @Casimir Crystal in the comment

Comment: According to the error message, is your command or script trying to access file `C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1\elevate.exe`, and which doesn't exist? Looks like it's copying the file from that path, but can't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron-builder cannot move downloaded into final location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751387/electron-builder-cannot-move-downloaded-into-final-location)

Comment: yes, but I restarted my computer and It worked